# imac and mbp display nscollectionview different way

Tags: macos, retina-display, nscollectionview

I have a collectionview and when I run the app on iMac the collectionview shows 3 columns in a row. (using flowlayout)

but from macbook pro, there is only two columns.

(cells are all displayed. so macbook pro has more rows.)

I just don't know what the problem is.

please give me a hint. thanks.

(Both iMac and MBP are retina display.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was really silly problem...

macOS global setting of scrollbar was 'always on'

That made my collection view narrow